# Using Build Variables in C code with Eclipse 4.4.2

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a project that I created previously using Eclipse 3.5.2.  In it, I was able to set a Build Variable in the project properties.  In this case, let's say I set `SW_VERSION` to be 4403.  Now this is intended to be a hex number, so in the Build Settings, I added a Symbol `"VERSION=0x${SW_VERSION}"` entry.  Then in my code, I was able to use `VERSION` as a regular number, like so:

```
unsigned int vers = VERSION;
```

There was no problems, and `vers` got the value `0x4403`.

Now I'm using Eclipse version 4.4.2 and I'm updating my project with some new features.  But first I'm just trying to re-compile my old project with the new toolchain, and while I don't get any messages on the Console, I get 3 warnings in the Problems tab:

```
Symbol 'SW_VERSION' could not be resolved
Symbol '$' could not be resolved
Statement has no effect 'VERSION'
```

I haven't tried running the completed project yet, but this concerns me and I have to assume that it won't actually work like it used to.  Is there some different way to do this in the newer Eclipse or is this feature just gone?

As a side note, there is a reason why I did it that way.  I also have the value of `SW_VERSION` appended to the end of my artifact name.  That part still works at least.

Comment: Which type of project are you using? Autotools, standard makefile ...

Comment: I'm letting Eclipse generate the makefiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexer (CDT parser) sees your VERSION macro and expands it to 0x${SW_VERSION}
but does not evaluate it so it passes it to preprocessor as is unexpanded,
these warning are coming from static code analysis and wont affect your binary. But since it annoying to see that you have to force indexer to see this macro properly by defining VERSION macro for indexer only

- project properties->C/C++ General->Preprocessor ..->
- Select GNU C (or whatever language variant you use)->
- Select CDT User Setting Entries
- Click Add... and add "Preprocessor macro" VERSION=1

It does not matter what number you put there since it won't be in your binaries, it is just for syntax parsing.

Comment: Wow, that is just, wow.  Makes the thing kind of pointless if it can't actually analyze what the code actually is.  I did this and it works, but it makes the pop-up macro expansion show this fake value rather than the real thing.  I'll live with it, but it seems like a real problem got added that it didn't use to have wrong with it.  Le sigh.

Comment: @JonS CDT has progressed massively in the 6 years since the previous version you used and unfortunately I am sad to see you found a regression. I would encourage you to file the bug report https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT. It may be that http://eclip.se/360155 is already such a report.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> Makes the thing kind of pointless if it can't actually analyze what the code actually is. I did this and it works, but it makes the pop-up macro expansion show this fake value rather than the real thing.

But I bet in Eclipse 3.5.2, the pop-up macro expansion wouldn't even come up for `VERSION`.

In other words, the indexer was *never* resolving `VERSION` correctly. The only thing that changed, I believe around Eclipse 3.7, is that indexer errors started to be surfaced in the UI, which I why you would have started seeing errors like `Symbol '$' could not be resolved`.

---

Now, regarding solving your problem: is the build output parser (`Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. -> Providers tab -> <Your Toolchain> Build Output Parser`) enabled?

It should be able to pick up the correct value of `VERSION` for the indexer, by parsing the output of the build, including the compiler invocations (which presumably contain the expanded value of `${SW_VERSION}`, otherwise compilation wouldn't work).

I don't have much experience with generated makefile projects (I write my own makefiles), but I think the build output parser should work for them too.