# How to set once variable for build and preprocessor in eclipse?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, variables, eclipse-cdt

I have a project that I'm "porting" from a weird makefile style to cdt eclipse builder.

I have issue trying to set once a variable in the **"Project Properties>C/C++ Build>Build variables"** tab.

Let's say `[Name]THIS_ADDRESS;[Type]String;[Value]0xFF30`

If doing so, the preprocessor, when trying to find THIS_ADDRESS in the foo.c file, fails.

```
//foo.c
#define MY_ADDRESS (THIS_ADDRESS + 12)
```

I get:

`Error[Pe029]: expected an expression`

I can add the definition in the **"Project Properties>C/C++ Build>Settings>C/C++ Compiler>Preprocessor>Defined Symbols"** tab, and then in the linker tab.
`THIS_ADDRESS=0xFF30` 
But this is quite redundant and source of error, especially if I have something like 20 defines.

I tried to set THIS_ADDRESS=$(THIS_ADDRESS) so the preprocessor variables takes the value of the build variable.

It does not work, so after I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780529/using-build-variables-in-c-code-with-eclipse-4-4-2), I added 
`[Preprocessor Macro]THIS_ADDRESS;[Value]0` in the **"Project Properties>C/C++ General>Preprocessor Include Paths,Macros etc..>CDT user Setting Entries"** tab.

but I get:

`Error[Pe007]: unrecognized token`

Is there a simple way to set only once a variable that could be used by the preprocessor and the builder, without modifying the code?

*By the way I'm on Eclipse Photon*

Comment: I think correct syntax is `${THIS_ADDRESS}`

Comment: I had a similar problem and my solution was to define global string substitutions in "Window>Preferences>Run/Debug>String Substitution" and then refer to these in my project settings like this `${SUBSTITUTION_VARIABLE}`. Then you can edit all variables at once in the string substitution settings.